# как правильно извлечь url по протоколу https из глобальной переменной $_SERVER

Tags: php, https

Суть в том, что в приложении есть файл init.php в котором определена переменная содержащая url главной страницы сайта. Но в ней определен путь по протоколу http. Как правильно прописать, чтобы получить путь по https?
Такая строка:
$app_path = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}";

Comment: `$app_path = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`

Comment: @InDevX , благодарю! Подскажите пожалуйста почему может так происходить, что когда я захожу на страницу из поиска, то она открывается по http и echo $app_path выводит хттп://mysite.ru/ , а если я в браузере набираю адрес с https, то открывается на https и echo выводит хттпс://mysite/

Comment: Значит надо настроить редирект http на https

Comment: @InDevX , благодарю